# Derive the Laplace Transform of the Modified Bessel Function of the first kind

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Derive the Laplace Transform of $I_0(\alpha t)$

Using the definition of Laplace Transform and also using Modified Bessel Function as  [Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PQJL.png) . Since the Modified Bessel function of the first kind is $I_n(z)$, n is equal to zero and $z$ will be equal to $\alpha t$. Derive its Laplace Transform.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html

Answer (score 1):

Since the wording of the question is very short, the wording of the answer is short as well :
$$\mathcal{L}_t\left(\text{I}_0(\alpha t)\right)(p)=\frac{1}{p^2-\alpha^2}$$

Comment: I edited the question, hope it helps.

Comment: I need the step by step solution for the  problem, using the definition of the Modified Bessel function as stated above. Thank you btw.

Comment: Sorry, to comply to the rules of the forum I am not allowed to give a step by step solution until your question be not marked "on hold".